how to compare form request with mysql table data if exist
I am flask starter. I was trying to loop through my mysql table data to check if the data in my form exists or I insert the form request in the table.
This is what I have tried but it only keep saving without comparing
@app.route('/createHotel', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def createHotel():
   names=''
   if "loggedin" in session and 'admin'==session['role']:
      user = session["username"]
      userid = session["userid"]
      cur.execute('SELECT name FROM hotels')
      h = cur.fetchall()
      i = 0
      while i < len(h):
        names = (h[i])
        i = i + 1
        if request.method == "POST" and 'name' in request.form and 'image' in request.form and 'city' in request.form:
         image = request.form["image"]
         name = request.form['name']
         city = request.form['city']
         features = request.form['features']
         RoomCount = request.form['RoomCount']
         peakSeasonRate = request.form['peakSeasonRate']
         OffPeakSeasonRate = request.form['OffPeakSeasonRate']
         if name != names:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO hotels (image, name, city, features, RoomCount, peakSeasonRate, OffPeakSeasonRate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (image, name, city, features, RoomCount, peakSeasonRate, OffPeakSeasonRate))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()
            flash('hotel added successfully', 'success')
            return redirect(url_for('hotelRecord'))
         else:
            flash('hotel  already exist in the database', 'success')
      return render_template("createHotel.html", user=user, userid=userid,)
   return redirect(url_for("home"))


don't use loop but get all values names = list(h) and use not in instead of != - if name not in names:

dont't use   for every line of code but select code and use Ctrl+K to format as one block

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Why return the name of all hotels? Can't you just look for a hotel with the name passed - SELECT name FROM hotels WHERE name = %s?

Thanks very much, I really appreciate your contribution

Don't use loop but get all values at once
names = list(h)

and use not in instead of != to check if new name is on this list
if name not in names:


If something doesn't work then you could add some print() to see which line of code is executed and what you have in variables.

     h = cur.fetchall()
     names = list(h)

     if request.method == "POST" and 'name' in request.form and 'image' in request.form and 'city' in request.form:
         image = request.form["image"]
         name = request.form['name']
         city = request.form['city']
         features = request.form['features']
         RoomCount = request.form['RoomCount']
         peakSeasonRate = request.form['peakSeasonRate']
         OffPeakSeasonRate = request.form['OffPeakSeasonRate']
         
         if name not in names:
             cur.execute('INSERT INTO hotels (image, name, city, features, RoomCount, peakSeasonRate, OffPeakSeasonRate) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (image, name, city, features, RoomCount, peakSeasonRate, OffPeakSeasonRate))
             mysql.connection.commit()
             cur.close()
             flash('hotel added successfully', 'success')
             return redirect(url_for('hotelRecord'))
         else:
             flash('hotel  already exist in the database', 'success')


BTW:
You may get form['name'] with empty string so better check if you get name -  ie.
if name and (name not in names):

